# Каким правилом обусловлена постановка запятой с тире?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

В процессе чтения учебника по синтаксису наткнулся на пример **периода** (подвид многочленного сложного предложения), где не совсем смог понять правило, которым обусловлена постановка запятой с  тире.
Сам пример:

> В 1800-х годах, в те времена, когда не было еще ни железных, ни
> шоссейных дорог, ни газового, ни стеаринового света, ни пружинных
> низких диванов, ни мебели без лаку, ни разочарованных юношей со
> стеклышками, ни либеральных философов-женщин, ни милых дам-камелий,
> которых так много развелось в наше время,— в те наивные времена, когда
> из Москвы, выезжая в Петербург в повозке или карете, брали с собой
> целую кухню домашнего приготовления, ехали восемь суток по мягкой
> пыльной или грязной дороге и верили в пожарские котлеты, в валдайские
> колокольчики и бублики,— когда в длинные осенние вечера нагорали
> сальные свечи, освещая семейные кружки из двадцати и тридцати человек,
> на балах в канделябры вставлялись восковые и спермацетовые свечи,
> когда мебель ставили симметрично, когда наши отцы были еще молоды не
> одним отсутствием морщин и седых волос, а стрелялись за женщин и из
> другого угла комнаты бросались поднимать нечаянно и не нечаянно
> уроненные платочки, наши матери носили коротенькие талии и огромные
> рукава и решали семейные дела выниманием билетиков; когда прелестные
> дамы-камелии прятались от дневного света,— в наивные времена масонских
> лож, мартинистов, тугендбунда, во времена Милорадовичей, Давыдовых,
> Пушкиных, — в губернском городе К. был съезд помещиков и кончались
> дворянские выборы.

Кажется, что если убрать тире, то будет чего-то не хватать...(первые три случая).

Кажется, что вместо запятой с тире поставить точку с запятой точно нельзя, ведь сами предложения несамостоятельны и не выражают законченной мысли - здесь ход моих мыслей верен, или я ошибаюсь?
Так же и просто запятую оставить не получится, ведь тогда потеряется та пауза, которая вроде как прослеживается в ходе такого длинного высказывания, которая, кажется, необходима?
Пока единственное объяснение, к которому я тяготею, - это что-то вроде такого: *запятая с тире стоит в этих местах, так как повторяется конструкция, используемая изначально при вводе придаточных.*

Получаются примерно следующие пары, которые (вроде как) образуют какой-то перекликающийся между собой параллелизм:

1. В те  времена, когда....в те наивные времена, когда...
2. В те времена, когда...когда в длинные осенние...
3. Когда в длинные осенние....в наивные времена...

В общем, уважаемые знатоки, к вам вопрос следующий, если всё же мне удалось его адекватно выразить: каким правилом или на основе какой мотивации поставлены запятые с тире в данном немаленьком предложении?

Это мой здесь первый вопрос, а еще я к тому же совсем новичок в русском языке (в плане осознанного изучения), поэтому буду премного благодарен за вашу помощь!

Comment: В самом начале ещё есть "в те времена, когда...", если это поможет. Похожее что-то на фольклорные повторы.

Comment: Ну если вы читаете учебник по синтаксису, там вроде должно быть объяснение.

Comment: У Розенталя есть тема:  Запятая и тире в качестве единого знака препинания ставятся в сложноподчиненном предложении:

1) перед главной частью, которой предшествует ряд однородных придаточных, если подчеркивается распадение сложного предложения на две части (перед главной частью делается длительная пауза).  Здесь предложение  распадается на несколько придаточных  и главную часть.  А что еще можно поставить?  Только единый знак.  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144#pp144

Comment: Вот я и об этом. Это тот случай. В учебнике должно было быть об этом написано.